# Algorithm for finding bags of elements in a sequence

Tags: algorithm, string-algorithm

Say that I have a sequence of elements of interest `A, B, C...` interspersed with don't care symbols `x`. I want to identify bags of elements from a predefined set of interesting combinations that happen within a predefined distance. There can be overlaps between the spans of symbols. For instance in the string `C x x A A x x C` the algo would detect twice the pattern `A A C` if max distance is 5.

For instance says that my set of interesting combinations is:

```
A A C
A B C
```

that I have a sequence:

```
B A x x C x x x A A x x x C
```

and that the maximum span is 5.

My algorithm should output:

```
B A x x C -> A B C
```

and will fail to identify pattern `A A C` since the span between elements of interest is greater than 5.

My intuition says that it is some kind of dynamic programming but maybe it is just an instance of a well known algorithm I'm not able to spot.

Any hint on what would be the approach/solution?

Comment: I'm a little confused of the goal here. So you're algorithm is supposed to consider n consecutive elements in a pre-set array, and return when it finds any group of elements of interests, regardless of order? do we count the number of times these sets/groups were found?

Comment: Yes, let me rephrase: Consider all possible brackets of 5 elements in my array. On those, find subsets of elements from a provided dictionary. Is it clearer now? Obviously considering all the possible brackets of elements means N-M brackets to check, that and then find the subsets, that it seems like wasteful for me. So my guess is that there is a clever way of doing it since I just focus on the elements of interest A, B, C....

Comment: The naive approach would be to just scan all sub-sequences of length 5 and check if it contains all elements from one of m interesting sets and thus be O(n*m). Do you want to optimize this or use precomputations?

Comment: I'd like to use the fact that there are lots of don't care symbols and that the dictionary of patterns is moderately big, instead of using brute force.

Comment: Yes, so for "bracket"/section {A, A, x, B, B}, if you're interested in {A,B}, then this increases the "count" of findings for {A,B} by 4?

Comment: @Elliott yes your are right. that would be 4 different pairs.

Comment: Is it strictly 5, or is this a variable length?

Comment: Yeah maybe I'm mislead. Talking with you somehow took me closer to the solution. Now the approach seems to me like consuming only elements of interest from the stream, creating brackets and then performing a backtracking search on the bracket using the dictionary of patterns.

Comment: No it is of variable length. 5 was to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Would `AABCx` match `AAC`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assign some names to describe the problem:

`m` = length of the array sequence (14 in your example)
`n` = total number of unique elements in the array sequence (3 in example)
`k` = length of each search region (5 in example)
`g` = number of groups that you're looking for (2 in example)

One option would be to summarise your data in each search region of size `k`. In your example, like this:

```
{B A x x C}
{A x x C x}
...
```

We make vectors of size `n` for each of these sections, first element represents the appearance of first type of element, say `A`

```
B A x x C --> [1,1,1] (one appearance of each)
A x x C x --> [1,0,1]
```

and so on.

We can do the same for our groups that we're searching for:

```
{A A C} --> [2,0,1]  
{A B C} --> [1,1,1]
```

Now the problem becomes obvious. Say we consider the summary of a search region, [3,2,5], and the summary of a group we're searching for, [0,1,2], we can calculate the number of combinations by recognising that we had 2 options for the second element, and (5x4)/(1x2) options for the third, so that's 20 options overall.

So for section summary, S, [s<sub>1</sub>, s<sub>2</sub>,..,s<sub>n</sub>], and a single group of interest, G, [g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>,...g<sub>n</sub>], we can calculate the total sum of ways we can extract G from S (c++ style code, except "!" means factorial):

```
int total_options = 1; // total ways to select G from S
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    if(g[i] == 0)
        continue; // this is an element that doesn't appear in G, so it shouldn't effect our count

    if(s[i] < g[i])
        return 0; // not enough elements in S for G

    for (int d = 1, f = s[i]; f > max(g[i], s[i] - g[i]); --f, ++d)
        total_options = total_options / d * f; // f, d are effectively factorials

    // the previous loop is a more efficient version of:
    // total_options *= (s[i]!) /(g[i]! * (s[i] - g[i])!);
}

return  total_options;
```

You would do this for each section, and each group that you're searching for.

Time complexity: O(`g*m*(k + n)`) (we must include `k` here because of the worst-case factorial calculation)

Space complexity:  O(`m + g*n`) (each section we could calculate as we go, so there's no need to store multiple sections simultaneously)

We can then improve on this by realising that each consecutive "section" only differs by considering the departing "tail" element, and the entering "head" element, so we should just calculate how these two change the "option count" as we iterate to the next section. We would do this by maintaining the previous "option count" calculation, and, NF (Number Fails), the number of elements in the region that were too low for the search group. The trick would be to maintain a positive "option count" which gets added to the grand total only if NF is 0. This would give you constant-time results for each `G` as you iterate over the main array of size `m`.

Time complexity: O(`g*m + g*n`)
Space complexity: O(`g*n + m`)

This algorithm has worst-case performance when each element in the main array is unique, and each of these elements appears at least once in some of the searches (otherwise we can treat any elements that don't appear in any of the searches to all be the same, like "x" in your example). So worst-case complexities can be simplified to:

Time complexity: O(`g*m`)
Space complexity: O(`g*m`)

I can't see how it'd be possible to get a better time complexity, but I'd be interested to know if some clever person can think of a method with lower space complexity.

If you don't know what I'm talking about when it comes to constant-time iteration by considering only the head and the tail, let me know and I'll explain with an example.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take all your interesting combinations and construct a tree such that interesting combinations lead to leaves and uninteresting ones do not. Sort first so that edges corresponding to earlier symbols are closer to the root.
2. Read the first five elements and increase frequency counters corresponding to the number of times each is seen.
3. Check the subset of up to five values by walking the tree according to the frequency counters. If you reach a leaf, emit the current match.
4. To slide the window, decrement the counter associated with the current leftmost interesting symbol, and increment counters for interesting symbols sucked in after sliding right.

Example #1:

```
AAC, ABC => (-)        [B A x x C] x x x A A x x x C
             |         f[A] = 1, f[B] = 1, f[C] = 1
             A         A->B->C, emit ABC
             |
            (-)        B [A x x C x] x x A A x x x C
            / \        f[B]--; A->x; continue
           A   B       
           |   |       B A x x [C x x x A] A x x x C
          (-) (-)      f[A]--; f[A]++; A->x; continue
           |   | 
           C   C       B A x x C x x x [A A x x x] C
           |   |       f[C]--; f[A]++; A->A->x; continue
          (+) (+)

                       B A x x C x x x A [A x x x C]
                       f[A]--; f[C]++; A->x; done
```

Example #2:

```
AAC => (-)             [C x x A A] x x C
        |              f[A]=2, f[B]=0, f[C]=1
        A              A->A->C, emit AAC; continue
        |
       (-)             C x x [A A x x C]
        |              f[C]--; f[C]++; A->A->C; emit AAC; done
        A
        |
       (-)
        |
        C
        |
       (+)
```

This solution should work regardless of window size and you can even allow interesting combinations of different sizes by marking interior nodes as matching (not just the leaves). This is going to be linear time and space in the number of elements in the input stream, though it will require some extra memory in terms of the number of interesting combinations and window size. The exact time/space analysis is left as an exercise.

Comment: As I understand from the comments `5:AB [AAxBB]` should count 4.  In fact, I think that `4:AB [AAxBB]` should count 4 also.  I don't think that your algorithm does this...

Comment: But I think that it could be adjusted to by making adding a frequency count for the search patterns also and taking the product of each `(character search count+1) - (character found count)` within the window once a tree match has been found.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Is one of the examples show wrong? Do you have a counterexample? I'm not sure I understand what I missed.

Comment: @RBarryYoung ah wait maybe I got it. [AAxBB] counts as four pairs, not two. Yeah, maybe this could be adjusted to potentially walk down the tree multiple times... but that's going to hurt performance, maybe badly

Comment: @RBarryYoung Maybe you're right about that, sort of does make sense...